# Android reading file from assets and storing in array list

Tags: java, android

My app needs to read from several files in the assets folder. But my file has delimiters $$$ and ||. The structure of the file is like this.

> Construction$$$
>   All the work involved in assembling resources and
>    putting together the materials required to form a new or changed
>    facility.||
>
> Construction Contractor$$$
>   A corporation or individual
>    who has entered into a contract with the organization to perform
>    construction work.||

The sentences ending with $$$ are to be stored in seperate array list and the sentences ending with || are to be stored on seperate array list.
How can i do this? Any sample or example code will be appreciated. Note that these files are very long.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("c.txt"))); //throwing a FileNotFoundException?
        String word;
        while((word=br.readLine()) != null)
            A_Words_array.add(word); //break txt file into different words, add to wordList
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            br.close(); //stop reading
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String[]words = new String[A_Words_array.size()];
    A_Words_array.toArray(words); //make array of wordList

    for(int i=0;i<words.length; i++)
        Log.i("Read this: ", words[i]);
```

Above is the code i found now how to split my sentences based upon ending delimiters?

Comment: Show us your code *work* please.

Comment: get each line from the file and check whether the particular string ends in $$$ and save it in a list and the same with ||

Comment: There is no code work for now. As my question explains everything @AVD

Comment: @SharathG a code would be helpfull

Comment: @MohsinShafqat Start reading files using BuffererReader and use String.split() method to split line data.

Comment: @SharathG Check he code in my edit

Answer (score 0):

Asuming that each sentence is in one line and they finish either with $$$ or ||, you can store the lines in different arrays depending on its endings:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.endsWith("$$$")) {
        list1.add(line);
    } else {
        list2.add(line);
    }
}
String[] dollarlines = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
String[] verticalLines = list2.toArray(new String[list2.size()]);
```